# VB.NET Deleting Text in Textbox Using Checkbox

Tags: vb.net

"can anyone help me in my problem

So i have this checkboxes, so what It does is if a select a checkbox the text of that checkbox will be passed to the HistoryTextbox

My main problem is that I am able to add new checkboxes to the HistoryTextbox, but when i uncheck the checkbox i want the text of the checkbox to be deleted in the HistoryTextbox

Example: When i click chkbox1 value of chkbox1 is ASTHMA
the HistoryTextbox should contain ASTHMA
Then i click again a new checkbox for hypertension
the HistoryTextbox should contain ASTHMA,HYPERTENSION
But When i uncheck the checkbox of ASTHMA the asthma will be the only one to be deleted or remove
and the HistoryTextbox will only contain the hypertension.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to give you guidance without seeing your code but you seem to be looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object,
                                      e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged,
                                                              CheckBox2.CheckedChanged,
                                                              CheckBox3.CheckedChanged ', etc.
    Dim currentCheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim textToAddOrRemove As String = currentCheckBox.Text & ","
    If currentCheckBox.Checked Then
        ' Add the text.
        HistoryTextbox.Text &= textToAddOrRemove
    Else
        ' Remove the text.
        HistoryTextbox.Text = HistoryTextbox.Text.Replace(textToAddOrRemove, String.Empty)
    End If
End Sub
```

Another option (especially useful if some of the CheckBoxes have the same text) is to generate the text each time based on the checked CheckBoxes. For example:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                CheckBox2.CheckedChanged,
                                                                                CheckBox3.CheckedChanged ', etc.
    Dim checkedCheckBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Where(Function(c) c.Checked)
    ' Or:
    'Dim checkedCheckBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}.Where(Function(c) c.Checked)

    HistoryTextbox.Text = String.Join(",", checkedCheckBoxes.Select(Function(c) c.Text))
End Sub
```